# git already updated local branch behind remote one after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have 2 branches. One is master, the other is dev.

Others developers have updated the remote master. I just pulled dev & master from remote.

So, my local dev & master should be the same with my remote dev&master.

Then, I did rebase for dev based on master. After this, I pushed my local dev to remote dev.

However, error occurred:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart

Why rebase will make my already updated local branch dev behind its remote
counterpart?

Comment: You probably just need a force push, i.e. use `git push --force origin dev`.  But beware of rebasing branches which are shared by other users.

Comment: Your commits id differs from the remote so the remote refuses your requests because rebase changes the commits.

Comment: In general, you should avoid rebasing branches that exist in the remote repository, as that will cause difficulties to your team. Rebasing is best reserved for private branches that only exist in your sandbox, before you push them. Once you've pushed, consider using merge instead. This Google search popped up lots of good pages about that topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+merge+vs+rebase+best+practice&oq=git+merge+vs+rebase+best+practice

Comment: dev is my personal branch, @TimBiegeleisen